# Show that $T(\vec{x}) = \vec{0}$ has non trival solutions

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T : R^n \rightarrow R^m$ be a linear transformation. Show that if $\{\vec{v_1}, \vec{v_2}\}$ is linearly independent in $R^n$ and $\{T(\vec{v_1}), T(\vec{v_2})\}$ is linearly dependent in $R^m$, then $T(\vec{x}) = \vec{0}$ has nontrivial solutions.

My take on this is that since $T(\vec{v_1}) = \vec{0}$ and $T(\vec{v_2}) = \vec{0}$ then then $A$ must not have any pivots in one of the lower rows. Since $A$ will always reduce to the same RREF form then an vector $\vec{x}$ will also be zero when $T(\vec{x}) = \vec{0}$ thus $T(\vec{x})$ produces a zero row and therefore has nontrivial solutions.

Im not sure if this is the right approach to this problem. Please let me know if I should change somthing. Thank you.

Comment: By the rank nullity theorem, $\ker(T)\ge 1$. So $T(x)=0$ for some $x\neq 0$.

Comment: $T(v_1)$ and $T(v_2)$ are not $0$ ... they are only linearly dependent, but this does not mean $0$. Btw, even if the previous comment is obviously correct, you could actually find an almost explicit solution of $T(x)=0$: what does it mean for *two* vectors to be linearly dependent?